# Table[ ] Output Cardinality

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The `Table[ ]` command usually returns a  list with the same cardinality of its iterator.

```
Table[i, {i,4}] 
(*
->{1,2,3,4}
*)
```

It is easy to show that is possible to return a list with a *greater* cardinality than the iterator

```
Table[Sequence @@ ConstantArray[1, i], {i, 2}]
(*
->{1,1,1}
*)
```

But ... Are there ways to return a list with *LESS* cardinality than the iterator?

Comment: `Table[Sequence @@ {}, {i, 10}]` ?

Comment: I find this an odd question.  May I know why you ask it?

Comment: @Mr. Bucause I want to get the best way to produce variable length lists by using an iterator with Table[]. As I commented below, you can use `Scan[IF[cond, AppendTo[]` for example, but I for some reason I tend to use Table, and then after using it, if I have to discard some values, I post-process. That is awful, and I'd rather prefer to discard the list elements on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example:

```
Table[Sequence @@ ConstantArray[1, i - 1], {i, 2}]
Out[1] = {1}
```

This need not always return a list with smaller cardinality. For e.g., `{i,3}` returns equal and `{i,4}` returns more.

Or an even sillier example would be

```
Table[Sequence @@ {}, {i, 2}]
```

but I don't know if it counts.

---

You could also use `Piecewise` inside `Table`

```
Table[Sequence @@ Piecewise[{
    {ConstantArray[1, i], i < 3},
    {ConstantArray[2, i], 3 <= i < 5},
    {{}, i >= 5}}],
 {i, 20}]

Out[2] = {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}
```

Comment: But I guess using `Sequence@@{}` and conditional constructs you could output whatever length you wish

Comment: @belisarius: Were you looking for an example that always returns a certain fixed number less than the iterator?

Comment: I usually use `Scan` with `IF[ cond, AppendTo[..] ]` when I need a variable length output. I want to see if someone comes up with something neat for using `Table` in this case.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
Table[Sequence @@ {}, {i, 10}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that I now understand your intent, I do not see the advantage to "on the fly" elimination within `Table` itself.  One could accomplish it with something like:

```
Table[If[EvenQ@i, i, ##&[]], {i, 25}]
```

but it is faster to use `Join`:

```
Join @@ Table[If[EvenQ@i, {i}, {}], {i, 25}]
```

or `DeleteCases`:

```
DeleteCases[Table[If[EvenQ@i, i], {i, 25}], , 1]
```

and in this simple case, `Select` is more than twice as fast:

```
Table[i, {i, 25}] ~Select~ EvenQ
```

If it is a matter of memory usage, the first method using `Sequence` does come out ahead, but the `Join` method is not far behind.

Comment: Postprocessing is always possible, but I _think_ increasingly inconvenient as the elements (for example images) grow. Suppose you want to convolve an image with a set of kernels and keep only those results satisfying certain criteria. Of course Table[] is not the better option, but I just want to get ideas on how to use it in those cases. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @belisarius, would you mind posting an example where you find post-processing inconvenient or problematic?

Comment: I am looking for alternative ideas, that's why I did not post a real example, as I have many ways to implement it. Sometimes I post dumb looking questions because what I look for is a subjective recommendation and those questions are at risk of being closed or even deleted in SO as "subjective or argumentative" and that will spoil the time others take in answering.