# Evaluate[] seems to not work inside Button[]

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

Any idea how to get this to work?

```
y = {}; Table[Button[x, AppendTo[y, Evaluate[x]]], {x, 5}]
```

Result: Click [`1`] , click [`2`], get `{6,6}`

I'm trivializing the actual task, but the goal is to set what a button does inside a `Map` or a `Table` or `ParallelTable`.

Please Help!

---

**EDIT**
Figured it out... `Evaluate` works at first level only. Here, it's too deep. So I used `ReplaceRule`:

```
Remove[sub]; y = {}; Table[Button[x, AppendTo[y, sub]] /. sub -> x, {x, 5}]
```

Comment: Please post `Remove[sub]; y = {}; Table[
 Button[x, AppendTo[y, sub]] /. sub -> x, {x, 5}]` as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replacement rules and pure functions offer concise alternatives to `With`. For example:

```
y={}; Range[5] /. x_Integer :> Button[x, AppendTo[y, x]]
```

or

```
y = {}; Replace[Range[5], x_ :> Button[x, AppendTo[y, x]], {1}]
```

or

```
y = {}; Array[Button[#, AppendTo[y, #]] &, {5}]
```

or

```
y = {}; Button[#, AppendTo[y, #]] & /@ Range[5]
```

For another example comparing these techniques, see my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470625/mathematica-table-function/6471024#6471024), where they are applied to a problem of creating a list of pure functions with parameter embedded in their body (closures).

Answer (score 10):

This is a job for `With`.  `With` is used to insert an evaluated expression into another expression at any depth -- even into parts of the expression that are not evaluated right away like the second argument to `Button`:

```
y = {}; Table[With[{x = i}, Button[x, AppendTo[y, x]]], {i, 5}]
```

In simple cases like this, some people (myself included) prefer to use the same symbol (`x` in this case) for both the `With` and `Table` variables, thus:

```
y = {}; Table[With[{x = x}, Button[x, AppendTo[y, x]]], {x, 5}]
```

Comment: +1. It is tangential to the current discussion, but at the bottom of my post in this thread: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/b07d6ff89313c70d, I defined a macro, which, when wrapped around `With[...]`, forces it to inject unevaluated expression(s) into its body. I mention it here because I thought you might find it interesting.

Comment: +1 For explaining the scoping construct in your ow words (and not WRI ones, which are not clear enough)

Answer (score 0):

`Evaluate` works at first level only. Here, it's too deep. So I used `ReplaceRule`:

```
Remove[sub]; y = {}; Table[ Button[x, AppendTo[y, sub]] /. sub -> x, {x, 5}]
```