# How to remove the Null symbol in a Table in Mathematica?

Tags: null, wolfram-mathematica

I need to use `If` inside of a `Table` loop, e.g. `Table[If[i< 3, i], {i, 5}]` will give `{1, 2, Null, Null, Null}`

But I want the result to be `{1,2}`.

Any fix for this?

EDIT:
What if we consider `Table[If[i< 3, f[i]], {i, 5}]` which gives `{f[1], f[2], Null, Null, Null}`

Comment: Somewhat related question:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/6313505/618728

Comment: Related question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3700/how-to-avoid-returning-a-null-if-there-is-no-else-condition-in-an-if-contruct

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Concisely:

```
Table[If[i < 3, i, ## &[]], {i, 5}]
```

This works because the function `## &` does not immediately evaluate.

`## &` is a "vanishing" function.

```
{1, 2, ## &[], 3, 4}
```

> ```
> ----> {1, 2, 3, 4}
> ```

See [SlotSequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SlotSequence.html) for more information.

Comment: @Leonid thanks for showing or reminding me of that some months ago.

Comment: I think this was your invention. I normally use `Sequence@@{}`, which is not as elegant (and may also be a tiny bit slower).

Comment: @Leonid; I believe that's correct, however I had been using `Unevaluated@Sequence[]` inside `If` before that.  (ps do you know how to search comments, apart from Google?  I'd like to find that exchange.)

Answer (score 15):

If you need to remove it from an existing list, you can use

```
DeleteCases[list, Null]
```

or

```
list /. Null -> Sequence[]
```

(a bit more advanced).

---

Regarding your `Table` example above, first note that the second comma in `If` is unnecessary (and is even highlighted in pink):

```
list = Table[If[i < 3, i], {i, 5}]
```

To filter the table elements by a condition, you might want to use something similar to

```
list = Select[Table[i, {i, 5}], # < 3 &]
```

instead.

---

Finally, if you need to generate the list without ever adding rejected elements to it (to save memory), I suggest using `Reap` and `Sow`:

```
Reap@Do[If[i < 3, Sow[i]], {i, 5}]
list = %[[2, 1]]
```

I haven't actually verified the memory usage of this compared to a plain `Table`, and note that if you generate only numbers, which can be stored in a [packed array](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/TechNotes/391/), the `Table` construct may be more memory efficient.  On the other hand if you generate a truly huge number of generic expressions, the majority of which will be rejected in `If`, `Sow` / `Reap` may be better.

Comment: +1. I actually implemented your last suggestion with `Reap-Sow` in full generality in the answer I linked to, in my answer (just may be syntax for condition could be friendlier).

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative, you may use the variation of `Table` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367932/generate-a-list-in-mathematica-with-a-conditional-tested-for-each-element/6368770#6368770), which has been designed specifically for conditional table-building. Here is how it will look:

```
In[12]:= tableGenAltMD[i,{i,5},#<3&]
Out[12]= {1,2}
```

The last argument is a function representing the condition. It actually would be nice to also have syntax where one could use `i` (and / or other iterator variables) directly, and such a syntax is probably not difficult to add.

Comment: Please consider illustrating why this may be preferred to the simplistic answer I gave below.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard For a very simple reason: this is a general function (my version). It handles multi-dimensional case as well, with a uniform syntax. It is still easier to read, and would be even easier when I add syntax to replace function by an expression for a condition. Should it have been a built-in function, or just simply WRI - approved one, there would be no question about using anything else. Imagine that you'd not have say `Cases`, and someone gives you one (implemented on the top-level). Would you not use it (if implementation is ok)? A lot of it is just about habits, conventions, etc.

Comment: Perhaps then you should include that in your answer? ;-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Don't think so :). There is enough information in it so that those who need it will find it.

Comment: Unless you are going to be obstinate and delete your preceding comment, at least it is now on this page. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I will keep the comment :). Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 5):

In the previous anwser, the part `## &[]` can be replaced by the built-in symbol `Nothing`

```
Table[If[i < 3, i, Nothing], {i, 5}]
```

gives

```
{1, 2}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use Sequence[] instead of Null, then you could do

```
Table[If[i < 3, i, Hold[Sequence[]]] // ReleaseHold, {i, 5}]
```

I wished for a long time that If would have Attribute SequenceHold. I think I once 
suggested this to WRI, but there are probably (good?) reasons for If to not hat this
attribute. 
One can try, if one dares to change built-in Symbols (which one should probably not do):

```
Unprotect[If];
SetAttributes[If, SequenceHold];
```

Then Sequence[] in If would just work:

```
Table[If[i < 3, i, Sequence[]], {i, 5}]
```

Comment: Rolf, please see the answer I just added.  I almost edited your question instead of posting it, but I realized that I would essentially replace your answer with mine, so I did not.

Comment: Mr. Wizard: very nice! I did not know about ##&@[] being a Sequence[] equivalent.